# PHP PDO- Is LIMIT 1 needed as part of the query when using fetch?

Tags: php

So `fetchAll` will return an array, but `fetch` will return only one result:

```
fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My question is, if I have many rows on the table, would it be faster to also include `LIMIT 1` in my query when using `fetch`, or is it totally unnecessary?

Comment: It's a really simple, but an interesting and valid question. I don't see why it was down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only going to fetch one row, it's a good idea to use `LIMIT 1`. This will reduce the load on the database, because it can stop processing the query as soon as it finds the first result. It also means less traffic over the network, because the server only needs to send back the first result; without this, the server will send lots of results that get buffered in the PDO library but never get used by the application.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required, but it will generally result in a faster response. The database will not have to compute/collect the whole result set and can potentially do many optimisations if the limit is known.